# User Authentication AMPscript functions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I note that if I create a CloudPage with any of the User Authentication AMPscript functions:

- AuthenticatedEmployeeID()
- AuthenticatedEmployeeNotificationAddress()
- AuthenticatedEmployeeUserName()
- AuthenticatedEnterpriseID()
- AuthenticatedMemberID()
- AuthenticatedMemberName()

...then when I publish the page, it just shows the user who **created** the landing page. For example, if I use:

```
%%=v(AuthenticatedEmployeeUserName())=%%
```

Then the page displays my SFMC user name. It doesn't matter which computer I view the page on (and whether the user has logged into Marketing Cloud), it will always display my name (as I originally created the page).

This begs the question; what's the purpose of these AMPscript functions? Are they simply not working in CloudPages or did they used to work at some point in time? (perhaps with the legacy landing pages?)

If anyone can share some insight that would be great.

Comment: What happens if you view it in private browsing mode?

Comment: Same behavior: I see my username. I was speaking to a contact last night and he thought that this used to work in legacy landing pages, so perhaps it's just broken in CloudPages.

Comment: Same issue here :( I also tried doing it in Mircosites as per what the documentation implies, but no luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this to work in CloudPages by assigning the functions to a variable:

```
%%[

var @EmployeeID
var @EmployeeNotificationAddress
var @EmployeeUserName
var @EnterpriseID
var @MemberID
var @MemberName

set @EmployeeID = AuthenticatedEmployeeID()
set @EmployeeNotificationAddress = AuthenticatedEmployeeNotificationAddress()
set @EmployeeUserName = AuthenticatedEmployeeUserName()
set @EnterpriseID = AuthenticatedEnterpriseID()
set @MemberID = AuthenticatedMemberID()
set @MemberName = AuthenticatedMemberName()

]%%
<br>EmployeeID: %%=v(@EmployeeID)=%%
<br>EmployeeNotificationAddress: %%=v(@EmployeeNotificationAddress)=%%
<br>EmployeeUserName: %%=v(@EmployeeUserName)=%%
<br>EnterpriseID: %%=v(@EnterpriseID)=%%
<br>MemberID: %%=v(@MemberID)=%%
<br>MemberName: %%=v(@MemberName)=%%
```

Output:

```
EmployeeID: 1234556
EmployeeNotificationAddress: doug@limedash.com 
EmployeeUserName: limedash_admin 
EnterpriseID: 1234567890
MemberID: 123456 
MemberName: Limedash
```

Comment: I have tested this myself - and it indeed does not clear the values when I log out of SFMC. Even when accessingh the URL from a different browser in private mode, it still shows my information.

Answer (score 0):

I also have tested above and get the same result on a cloud page ( not clearing values when accessing from a different browser or logout of SFMC.

If you read the developer documentation for the Authenticated functions they state that

1. you need to have micro sites functionality activated for your account
2. configure Sender Authenticated Redirection in microsite.
3. not  for use with cloud pages

See:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/authenticatedemployeeid.htm?search_text=AuthenticatedEmployeeID()