# Is there an amspcript variable/substitution for 'current user'?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, user, landing-page

I have built a landing page which is for internal users only - it has System Authenticated Redirection on it. I'm using it to create data extensions using some scripts and ampscript to fire automations.

When this creates data extensions, we write 'Created by USER on DATE' in the DE description field. Is there a way to populate USER with the name of the person who ran it?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the ampscript function [AuthenticatedEmployeeUserName()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/authenticatedemployeeusername.htm) is what you are looking for.

> AuthenticatedEmployeeUserName
>
> Overview
>
> Returns the username of the  authenticated landing page user. Use this 
>   function only with Microsites when using Sender Authenticated Redirection. Not 
>   for use with CloudPages.
>
> Syntax `AuthenticatedEmployeeUserName()`
>
> Usage
>
> `set @username = AuthenticatedEmployeeUserName()`
>
> The system sets @username to the value of the username for the authenticated 
>   landing page user.

Comment: Contrary to the official docs, I was able to get this to work in CloudPages: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/232422/5202

Comment: That is awesome @AdamSpriggs! Great find and thanks for sharing!